# iPad Overlay does not completely cover screen

Tags: iphone, html, css, ipad, overlay

I use a modal div as overlay to kind of disable the background page while the overlay DIV is open. Here is the code;

```
#TB_overlay {
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

Now this works fine on desktop browsers, but on the iPad, the overlay window only covers upto the screen height and not the entire page. How do I fix this issue?

I know there are some known position:fixed issues and also giving a fixed px height value can fix this issue?

But please let me know if there is any other workaround for this issue.

Comment: What do you mean "screen height but not the entire page?" Do you have a screenshot for us to see?

Comment: position: fixed is not work in ipad & iphone

Comment: When I say screen height, I actually meant the visible browser height (or say the visual viewport height of around 768px)...Also i am aware position: fixed does not work in iPad..that is the reason I am looking for a workaround and not a solution...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Conveniently enough the iPad supports:

```
<link rel=”stylesheet” media=”all and (orientation:portrait)” href=”css/portrait.css”>
```

and/or

```
 <link rel=”stylesheet” media=”all and (orientation:landscape)” href=”css/landscape.css”>
```

I recommend using min-width / min-height in your ipad.css file.

Comment: How does this help in acheiving what I want for the overlay issue?

Comment: Then you need to define your question more thoroughly instead of editting it afterwards

Comment: I have not edited my question afterwards...Where do you see the "Edit" link in my question ?

Comment: While this is an answer, it doesn't address the question at hand. Please consider revising?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this on my site by using jQuery to calculate the size of the whole page and then setting the overlay height accordingly.